# How to cross project plan for enterprise resources, with leveling support in Microsoft Project Server

Tags: ms-project, resource-planning, project-server

I'm using Microsoft Project Server on Sharepoint to manage project throughout the organization.
I have some enterprise (work) resources, that are simultaneously active on multiple projects.
The resource is working for each project for an specified portion of his weekly calendar. I prefer to keep using enterprise resources rather than local resources for each project.

What is the best solution to manage that, in a way that give me ability to automatically level task assignments based on these constraints?

I've already tried following options without luck:

- Changing calendar for the resource (which changes it for all projects)
- Using resource engagement feature (that seems to be a tool for collaboration, rather than having actual functionality in assignments)
- Changing resource availability (which affects all projects)

Comment: What is the issue you're experiencing using the leveling functionality with enterprise resources?

Comment: @DavidEspina The leveling does not consider other projects. Consider the time when none of projects are planned yet, and you want use leveling, and you want to split the weekly calendar of different resources among projects. What can you do to level tasks automatically? I have no idea.

Comment: I won't put this in an answer because it does not answer your question, but my practice has been to avoid auto leveling because its outcome typically is not useful (I have never found it to be).  From my view, you need to build it manually and level manually to a reasonable degree (never perfectly leveled).  Just another perspective.  Hope it helps a little.